# Tell UITabBar which view to load

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitabbar

Is there a way to load views according to some states when touchingon UITabBar button?
For example I touch "Home" button View1 loads. Than i do some code and when i touch "Home" button again View2 loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done ...Suppose we have two view in memory **myView1** & **myView2**..

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
     if(OnPressHomeTabBarButton) // Put your condition at this place  
     {
        [myView1 removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:myView2];

     }
     else 
     { 
        [myView2 removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:myView1];
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the property [viewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW3).

Look at this note from the documentation:

> If you change the value of this
>   property at runtime, the tab bar
>   controller removes all of the old view
>   controllers before installing the new
>   ones. The tab bar items for the new
>   view controllers are displayed
>   immediately and are not animated into
>   position. When changing the view
>   controllers, the tab bar controller
>   remembers the view controller object
>   that was previously selected and
>   attempts to reselect it. If the
>   selected view controller is no longer
>   present, it attempts to select the
>   view controller at the same index in
>   the array as the previous selection.
>   If that index is invalid, it selects
>   the view controller at index 0.